# How to pass a table name as a variable to Java/Spring?

Tags: java, sql, spring

I want to display table data based on the table name entered. How to make the tablename variable? I tried to create a generic type and DAO but there isn't a generic RowMapper to use with getJdbcTemplate. If I use EntityManager instead of the template, it crashes. I am a beginner in Spring stuff. The function I have now is something like this:

```
public List<T> findFromTable(String tableName) {
    return getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT * from " + 
tableName).getResultList();
}
```